# How do I reset a balance of a sandbox business account in the new developer UI?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am testing the mass payout functionality. We use a test business account to hold balance, and pay out to customers, then verify that the fund has been transferred.

With the old UI, I used to be able to 'reset' the sandbox account once in a while so that we put back some cash to the balance.

With the new developer UI, however, there doesn't seem to be a way to do that. Has anyone able to reset the balance of a sandbox business account?

Answer (score 2):

We’ll pass the feedback along to add that functionality.  In the meantime, you should be able to send a payment from one of your other test accounts (we'll call it account A) to the account that’s sending the Mass Pay transactions (account B), giving it a balance.

To do so:

Log in to Account A> click Send Money > enter the email address for account B > enter amount you want to send > click Continue > click Send Money.

Account B will now have a balance and be able to send Mass Payments.

Comment: Workaround worked fine for now. Hope the issue gets addressed soon.

Comment: In case there is any confusion, I wanted to add that you log into sandbox.paypal.com using Account A, and then you will be able to see the new account balance for Account B when you log into developer.paypal.com.